# Relation between forward bias and current in a diode

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, solid-state-devices

I have seen the VI graph to depict the relationship between forward bias and current. (left graph) and I think I get it. I have also seen another graph (right graph) to depict the relation between forward bias and current.

Are both these graphs depicting the same relationship?

If so, why they look different for the forward bias part?

[image]

Comment: Translate the readings from the log Y axis scale (RH) to linear Y axis and see for yourself.

Comment: Are you familiar with: Semi log plots https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-log_plot

Answer (score 3):

They are both exactly the same graphs, but with different axis. Your left graph has a linear scale on both axis, while the graph on the right uses a logarithmic scale for the current (notice how the current changes always one magnitude: 0.01mA, 0.1mA, 1mA, ...).

Answer (score 2):

They are somewhat the same graph. However, the graph on the right has a semi-log axis, has current on the vertical axis, and covers a much smaller voltage range than the one on the left.

Why the differences?

If you look at the [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation), current should grow exponentially with voltage:

$$ I \propto e^V - 1 $$

From the same article, there is a plot of this equation both on a linear and logarithmic axis:

[image]
Thingmaker, CC BY-SA 4.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0, via Wikimedia Commons

Notice how when current is on a log scale, the function is just a straight line.

Now looking back at your plot on the right, notice how this is only approximately true up to about 0.9V. After that, current grows significantly more slowly than exponentially.

The reason: real diodes aren't ideal. Besides the behavior modeled by the Shockley diode equation, they have non-ideal behavior like resistance. At low currents this resistance isn't very significant, and the voltage-current relationship is approximately exponential. At higher currents the resistance dominates, and the voltage-current relationship is approximately linear, like a resistor.

The exponential current-voltage relationship of a diode at sufficiently low current is a useful property in many applications. Besides just using a diode to rectify current, it can also be used as an analog calculator. [Op-amps can add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Summing_amplifier), and they can also invert, so they can subtract. Adding a diode gives access to exponentials and logarithms, which means [you can also multiply and divide](https://biosci.mcdb.ucsb.edu/biochemistry/tw-lig/logarithms/logarithmic-algebra.htm).  But for this to work the diode must be kept in the region where its current-voltage relationship is exponential. Your graph on the right makes it easy to see the diode's behavior in this region, which on the left graph is too small to read with sufficient detail.